# JUnit skipped tests NOT appearing in main report columns but appear in packages reports columns

Tags: java, junit, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

In our team we are getting JUnit test results reports with Jenkins plugin.
But we only get skipped tests (the ones with the Java annotation with @Ignore) at the package level.
For the main report result window, we only get Fail and Total.

Check these images:

**Main Test Result Report**

You can see there are 138 skipped tests, but no one is shown at package level in the columns.
Only *Fail* and *Total* columns are shown:

[image]

**Package Test Result Report**

At the package level, skipped tests are shown indeed in the columns: *Failed*, *Skip* and *Total*.

[image]

Is it possible to see the Skip column in the Main Test Result Report?

Thanks in advance,
Tomas.